# PyQT5 запись видео

Tags: python, pyqt5, opencv, запись, камера

Я хочу написать простую программу для записи с веб камеры используя `PyQt5` и `OpenCV`.

Мне нужно записывать видео при нажатии кнопки `START`. И остановить запись нажав `STOP`. При этом поток с камеры всегда выводится в окно.

На выходе у меня получается видео с нулевой длительностью и выглядит так, как будто захватывает только первый кадр.

```
import sys
import cv2
import os

from datetime import datetime
from ui_main_window import *

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    # class constructor
    def __init__(self):
        # call QWidget constructor
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        # create a timer
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.saveTimer = QTimer()
        # set timer timeout callback function
        self.saveTimer.timeout.connect(self.viewCam)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.viewCam)
        #always shows video in window
        self.timer.start()
        # set control_bt callback clicked  function
        self.ui.control_bt.clicked.connect(self.controlTimer)
        self.cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(cv2.CAP_DSHOW, 0)
        self.cap1.set(3,480)
        self.cap1.set(4,640)
        self.cap1.set(5,30)

    # view camera
    def viewCam(self):
        # read image in BGR format
        ret1, image1 = self.cap1.read()      
        # convert image to RGB format
        im1 = cv2.cvtColor(image1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        # get image infos
        height1, width1, channel1 = im1.shape
        step1 = channel1 * width1
        # create QImage from image
        qImg1 = QImage(im1.data, width1, height1, step1, QImage.Format_RGB888)
        # show image in img_label
        self.ui.image_label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(qImg1))

    # start/stop timer
    def controlTimer(self):
        # if timer is stopped
        if not self.saveTimer.isActive():
            # create video capture
            self.path = os.makedirs('C:/camera/' + datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d__%H-%M-%S'))
            self.fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')
            self.out1 = cv2.VideoWriter(os.path.join('C:/camera/' + datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d__%H-%M-%S'), 'video.avi'), self.fourcc, 30, (640,480))
            #start writing
            self.saveTimer.start()
            self.timer.stop()
            ret1, image1 = self.cap1.read()
            if ret1:
                self.out1.write(image1)
            # update control_bt text
            self.ui.control_bt.setText("STOP")
        # if timer is started
        else:
            # stop writing
            self.saveTimer.stop()
            self.timer.start()
            self.out1.release()
            # update control_bt text
            self.ui.control_bt.setText("START")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Вам нужна многопоточность, иначе у вас залочится gui - первый поток - получает изображение с камеры, конвертирует его и передает дальше, второй - главный поток приложения, выводит на экран полученное изображение, третий - записывает в файл

Comment: вы забыли опубликовать модуль `ui_main_window.py`

Comment: @S.Nick у него там одна кнопка `control_bt` и одна метка `image_label`

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Огромное спасибо за совет! Ниже публикую получившийся код. Остается проблема с записанным видео. Оно воспроизводится, но все еще имеет нулевую длительность. Не могу его перематывать. Может проблема в `self.out.release()` ?

Comment: Не знаю. Надо гуглить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
import cv2
import os

from datetime import datetime
#from ui_main_window import *

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QThread, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class Thread1(QThread):
    changePixmap = pyqtSignal(QImage)
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        self.cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(cv2.CAP_DSHOW, 0)
        self.cap1.set(3,480)
        self.cap1.set(4,640)
        self.cap1.set(5,30)
        while True:
            ret1, image1 = self.cap1.read()
            if ret1:
                im1 = cv2.cvtColor(image1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                height1, width1, channel1 = im1.shape
                step1 = channel1 * width1
                qImg1 = QImage(im1.data, width1, height1, step1, QImage.Format_RGB888)
                self.changePixmap.emit(qImg1)


class Thread2(QThread):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.active = True

    def run(self):
        if self.active:         
# !!!                             # установите свой путь !!!     
            self.path = os.makedirs('D:/_Qt/__Qt/camera/' + datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d__%H-%M-%S'))
            self.fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')
# !!!                                             # установите свой путь !!!  
            self.out1 = cv2.VideoWriter(os.path.join('D:/_Qt/__Qt/camera/' + datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d__%H-%M-%S'), 'video.avi'), self.fourcc, 30, (640,480))
            self.cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(cv2.CAP_DSHOW, 0)
            self.cap1.set(3, 480)
            self.cap1.set(4, 640)
            self.cap1.set(5, 30)
#            while True:
            while self.active:                          # +
                ret1, image1 = self.cap1.read()
                if ret1:
                    self.out1.write(image1)     
                self.msleep(10)                         # +   

    def stop(self):
#        if self.active == False:
        self.out1.release()

       
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(660, 520)
#        self.ui = Ui_Form()
#        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.control_bt = QPushButton('START')
        self.control_bt.clicked.connect(self.controlTimer)
        self.image_label = QLabel()
        
        self.saveTimer = QTimer()
        
        self.th1 = Thread1(self)
        self.th1.changePixmap.connect(self.setImage)
        self.th1.start()
        
        vlayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vlayout.addWidget(self.image_label)
        vlayout.addWidget(self.control_bt)   

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QImage)
    def setImage(self, qImg1):
        self.image_label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(qImg1))

    def controlTimer(self):
        if not self.saveTimer.isActive():
            # write video
            self.saveTimer.start()
            self.th2 = Thread2(self)
            self.th2.active = True                                # +
            self.th2.start()
#            self.active = True
            # update control_bt text
            self.control_bt.setText("STOP")
        else:
            # stop writing
            self.saveTimer.stop()
#            self.active = False
            self.th2.active = False                   # +
            
            self.th2.stop()                           # +
            self.th2.terminate()                      # +
            # update control_bt text
            self.control_bt.setText("START")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: Попытался добавить еще 2 потока для записи с двух камер. При этом картинка со второй камеры появляется в окне с задержкой. При нажатии старт программа вылетает. Дебаггер сообщает Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005). В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: @Alex  1. чтобы получить реальное сообщение об ошибке - всегда запускайте приложение в CMD/консоле/терминале.  2. попробуйте в дополнительных потоках добавить небольшую задержку, например  `self.msleep(10)`. 3. Если у вас возникают другие вопросы, задайте их, сформировав новый вопрос и не забывайте публиковать ВСЕ необходимые модули, чтобы ваш пример был ВОСПРОИЗВОДИМЫМ!