# PyQT5 запись видео с двух камер

Tags: python, pyqt5, opencv, запись, камера

Я пытаюсь сделать программу для записи видео с двух камер используя PyQt5 и OpenCV. Вопрос записи с одной камеры был решен благодаря https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1150993/396441

Я попытался добавить дополнительные потоки для вывода в окно и записи. При этом картинка со второй камеры появляется в окне с задержкой. Затем при нажатии START программа вылетает, в терминале сообщений нет. Дебаггер сообщает Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005).

**main_window.py**

```
import sys
import cv2
import os

from datetime import datetime
from ui_main_window import *

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QThread, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')

class Thread1(QThread):
    changePixmap1 = pyqtSignal(QImage)
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        self.cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(cv2.CAP_DSHOW, 0)
        self.cap1.set(3,480)
        self.cap1.set(4,640)
        self.cap1.set(5,30)
        while True:
            ret1, image1 = self.cap1.read()
            if ret1:
                im1 = cv2.cvtColor(image1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                height1, width1, channel1 = im1.shape
                step1 = channel1 * width1
                qImg1 = QImage(im1.data, width1, height1, step1, QImage.Format_RGB888)
                self.changePixmap1.emit(qImg1)

class Thread2(QThread):
    changePixmap2 = pyqtSignal(QImage)
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        #self.msleep(10)
        self.cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture(1, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
        self.cap2.set(3,480)
        self.cap2.set(4,640)
        self.cap2.set(5,30)
        while True:
            ret2, image2 = self.cap2.read()
            if ret2:
                im2 = cv2.cvtColor(image2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                height2, width2, channel2 = im2.shape
                step2 = channel2 * width2
                qImg2 = QImage(im2.data, width2, height2, step2, QImage.Format_RGB888)
                self.changePixmap2.emit(qImg2)

class Thread3(QThread):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.active = True

    def run(self):
        if self.active:
            self.path = os.makedirs('C:/camera/' + datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d__%H-%M-%S'))
            self.out1 = cv2.VideoWriter(os.path.join('C:/camera/' + datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d__%H-%M-%S'), 'cam1.avi'), fourcc, 30, (640,480))
            self.cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(cv2.CAP_DSHOW, 0)
            self.cap1.set(3,480)
            self.cap1.set(4,640)
            self.cap1.set(5,30)
            while self.active:
                ret1, image1 = self.cap1.read()
                if ret1:
                    self.out1.write(image1)
                self.msleep(10)

    def stop(self):
            self.out1.release()

class Thread4(QThread):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.active = True

    def run(self):
        if self.active:
            #self.msleep(10)
            self.out2 = cv2.VideoWriter(os.path.join('C:/camera/' + datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d__%H-%M-%S'), 'cam2.avi'), fourcc, 30, (640,480))
            self.cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture(1, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
            self.cap2.set(3,480)
            self.cap2.set(4,640)
            self.cap2.set(5,30)
            while self.active:
                ret2, image2 = self.cap2.read()
                if ret2:
                    self.out2.write(image2)
                self.msleep(10)

    def stop(self):
            self.out2.release()    

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.saveTimer = QTimer()
        self.ui.control_bt.clicked.connect(self.controlTimer)
        self.th1 = Thread1(self)
        self.th2 = Thread2(self)
        self.th1.changePixmap1.connect(self.setImage1)
        self.th2.changePixmap2.connect(self.setImage2)
        self.th1.start()
        self.th2.start()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QImage)
    def setImage1(self, qImg1):
        self.ui.image_label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(qImg1))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QImage)
    def setImage2(self, qImg2):
        self.ui.image_label_2.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(qImg2))

    def controlTimer(self):
        if not self.saveTimer.isActive():
            self.saveTimer.start()
            self.th3 = Thread3(self)
            self.th3.start()
            self.th3.active = True
            self.th4 = Thread4(self)
            self.th4.start()
            self.th4.active = True
            self.ui.control_bt.setText("STOP")
        else:
            self.saveTimer.stop()
            self.th3.active = False
            self.th3.stop()                           
            self.th3.terminate()
            self.th4.active = False
            self.th4.stop()                           
            self.th4.terminate()
            self.ui.control_bt.setText("START")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**ui_main_window.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.NonModal)
        Form.resize(1320, 652)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(Form.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        Form.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        Form.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1320, 652))
        self.control_bt = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.control_bt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(570, 510, 171, 81))
        self.control_bt.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(171, 81))
        self.control_bt.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(171, 81))
        self.control_bt.setCheckable(True)
        self.control_bt.setChecked(False)
        self.control_bt.setAutoExclusive(False)
        self.control_bt.setObjectName("control_bt")
        self.image_label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.image_label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(670, 10, 640, 480))
        self.image_label_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(640, 480))
        self.image_label_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(640, 480))
        self.image_label_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Panel)
        self.image_label_2.setObjectName("image_label_2")
        self.image_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.image_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 640, 480))
        self.image_label.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(640, 480))
        self.image_label.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(640, 480))
        self.image_label.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Panel)
        self.image_label.setObjectName("image_label")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Camera"))
        self.control_bt.setText(_translate("Form", "START"))
        self.image_label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><br/></p></body></html>"))
        self.image_label.setText(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><br/></p></body></html>"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: можите дополнительно написать тезисно в чём решение ?

Comment: @Интик полагаю проблема была в инициализации камер внутри потоков.

Answer (score 2):

я не могу проверить ваш пример, потому что у меня нет второй камеры.

Предлагаю вам попробовать установить, например `self.msleep(7)`
во всех методах `def run(self):` дополнительных потоков. Напишите, что у вас получается.

```
...
class Thread1(QThread):
    changePixmap1 = pyqtSignal(QImage)
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        self.cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(cv2.CAP_DSHOW, 0)
        self.cap1.set(3,480)
        self.cap1.set(4,640)
        self.cap1.set(5,30)
        while True:
            ret1, image1 = self.cap1.read()
            if ret1:
                im1 = cv2.cvtColor(image1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                height1, width1, channel1 = im1.shape
                step1 = channel1 * width1
                qImg1 = QImage(im1.data, width1, height1, step1, QImage.Format_RGB888)
                self.changePixmap1.emit(qImg1)
                
            self.msleep(7)                         # +++
...

...
class Thread2(QThread):
    changePixmap2 = pyqtSignal(QImage)
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        #self.msleep(10)
        self.cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture(1, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
        self.cap2.set(3,480)
        self.cap2.set(4,640)
        self.cap2.set(5,30)
        while True:
            ret2, image2 = self.cap2.read()
            if ret2:
                im2 = cv2.cvtColor(image2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                height2, width2, channel2 = im2.shape
                step2 = channel2 * width2
                qImg2 = QImage(im2.data, width2, height2, step2, QImage.Format_RGB888)
                self.changePixmap2.emit(qImg2)
                
            self.msleep(7)                         # +++
...

...
class Thread3(QThread):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.active = True

    def run(self):
        if self.active:
            self.path = os.makedirs('D:/_Qt/__Qt/camera/' + datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d__%H-%M-%S'))
            self.out1 = cv2.VideoWriter(os.path.join('D:/_Qt/__Qt/camera/' + datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d__%H-%M-%S'), 'cam1.avi'), fourcc, 30, (640,480))
            self.cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(cv2.CAP_DSHOW, 0)
            self.cap1.set(3,480)
            self.cap1.set(4,640)
            self.cap1.set(5,30)
            while self.active:
                ret1, image1 = self.cap1.read()
                if ret1:
                    self.out1.write(image1)
                    
                self.msleep(7)                         # +++
...

...
class Thread4(QThread):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.active = True

    def run(self):
        if self.active:
            #self.msleep(10)
            self.out2 = cv2.VideoWriter(os.path.join('D:/_Qt/__Qt/camera/' + datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d__%H-%M-%S'), 'cam2.avi'), fourcc, 30, (640,480))
            self.cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture(1, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
            self.cap2.set(3,480)
            self.cap2.set(4,640)
            self.cap2.set(5,30)
            while self.active:
                ret2, image2 = self.cap2.read()
                if ret2:
                    self.out2.write(image2)
                    
                self.msleep(7)                          # +++

...
```

Comment: Пробую. Проблема все еще сохраняется.

Comment: @Alex картинка со второй камеры появляется в окне с задержкой ? при нажатии START программа вылетает, также как и ранее ? Файлы пишутся ? ... У меня все работало без ошибок, только запись со второй камеры в файл пишет только метку.

Comment: Да, появляется с задержкой. При нажатии старт вылетает. Создается два файла по 6кБ.

Comment: cv2.VideoCapture(1, cv2.CAP_DSHOW) .... cv2.VideoCapture(cv2.CAP_DSHOW, 0) - возможно опечатка

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему следующим образом

**main_window.py**

```
import sys
import cv2
import os

from datetime import datetime
from ui_main_window import *

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QThread, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')

cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(cv2.CAP_DSHOW, 0)
cap1.set(3,480)
cap1.set(4,640)
cap1.set(5,30)

cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture(1, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
cap2.set(3,480)
cap2.set(4,640)
cap2.set(5,30)

class Thread1(QThread):
    changePixmap1 = pyqtSignal(QImage)
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        while cap1.isOpened():
            ret1, image1 = cap1.read()
            if ret1:
                im1 = cv2.cvtColor(image1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                height1, width1, channel1 = im1.shape
                step1 = channel1 * width1
                qImg1 = QImage(im1.data, width1, height1, step1, QImage.Format_RGB888)
                self.changePixmap1.emit(qImg1)
                
            #self.msleep(7)     

class Thread2(QThread):
    changePixmap2 = pyqtSignal(QImage)
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        while cap2.isOpened():
            ret2, image2 = cap2.read()
            if ret2:
                im2 = cv2.cvtColor(image2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                height2, width2, channel2 = im2.shape
                step2 = channel2 * width2
                qImg2 = QImage(im2.data, width2, height2, step2, QImage.Format_RGB888)
                self.changePixmap2.emit(qImg2)
                
            #self.msleep(7)

class Thread3(QThread):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.active = True

    def run(self):
        if self.active:
            self.path = os.makedirs('C:/camera/' + datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d__%H-%M-%S'))
            self.out1 = cv2.VideoWriter(os.path.join('C:/camera/' + datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d__%H-%M-%S'), 'cam1.avi'), fourcc, 30, (640,480))
            while self.active:
                ret1, image1 = cap1.read()
                if ret1:
                    self.out1.write(image1)
                    
                #self.msleep(7)

    def stop(self):
            self.out1.release()

class Thread4(QThread):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.active = True

    def run(self):
        if self.active:
            self.out2 = cv2.VideoWriter(os.path.join('C:/camera/' + datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d__%H-%M-%S'), 'cam2.avi'), fourcc, 30, (640,480))
            while self.active:
                ret2, image2 = cap2.read()
                if ret2:
                    self.out2.write(image2)
                    
                #self.msleep(7)

    def stop(self):
            self.out2.release()    

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.saveTimer = QTimer()
        self.ui.control_bt.clicked.connect(self.controlTimer)
        self.th1 = Thread1(self)
        self.th2 = Thread2(self)
        self.th1.changePixmap1.connect(self.setImage1)
        self.th2.changePixmap2.connect(self.setImage2)
        self.th1.start()
        self.th2.start()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QImage)
    def setImage1(self, qImg1):
        self.ui.image_label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(qImg1))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QImage)
    def setImage2(self, qImg2):
        self.ui.image_label_2.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(qImg2))

    def controlTimer(self):
        if not self.saveTimer.isActive():
            self.saveTimer.start()
            self.th3 = Thread3(self)
            self.th3.start()
            self.th3.active = True
            self.th4 = Thread4(self)
            self.th4.start()
            self.th4.active = True
            self.ui.control_bt.setText("STOP")
        else:
            self.saveTimer.stop()
            self.th3.active = False
            self.th3.stop()                           
            self.th3.terminate()
            self.th4.active = False
            self.th4.stop()                           
            self.th4.terminate()
            self.ui.control_bt.setText("START")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```